# Elimination when a player loses all herds, but still has a Chupacabra

Tags: chupacabra

I'm looking for a rules clarification for "[Chupacabra: Survive the Night](http://www.sjgames.com/dice/chupacabra/)" by Steve Jackson Games.

The [rules](http://www.sjgames.com/dice/chupacabra/img/chupacabra_rules.pdf) state:

> Any player who loses all his dice is out of the game, even if he hasn't attacked yet on that round!

If a player rolls a combination of herds and at least one Chupacabra and all of their herds are taken are they eliminated? They still have at least one dice because of the Chupacabra.

The clause stating "even if they haven't attacked" seems to allow for them to have Chupacabras and still be eliminated.

Comment: @bwarner I guess that answers [my question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/how-should-chupacabra-survive-the-night-be-tagged)

Comment: @murgatroid Not necessarily, if someone else decides it should be something else, that's fine.  I just wanted to give it an actual game tag of some sort, and figure we don't tend to care about the subtitles.

Comment: Asked in June? Bah. All that work calling SJG for nothing.  I thought this was a new question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From talking (on the phone) with the lovely people at Steve Jackson Games in Austin:

If you still have a die, you're still in the game.

Rolling a Chupacabra essentially means you're safe and can't get kicked out of the game that round. There's no way to "kill" a fellow Chupacabra.

I think that when the game rules say "Even if they haven't attacked" they mean "Even if they haven't had a turn yet".